# Grails 2.4.4 is using deleted i18n files

Tags: grails, caching, intellij-idea, internationalization

My system default to the Locale: "iw", I created a few Locale files:

messages_iw.properties,
messages.properties

I check that grails indeed change the language file depending on the system locale and it did.

after this test i deleted the first file(messages_iw.properties) and lunched the grails server again (With IntelliJ + tomcat 8).

For some reason grails still referencing the file that i DELETED! how is it possible? i looked for this file everywhere and it doesn't exists. why does grails use a file i already deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably cached in a subdirectory of the `target` directory. Run

```
grails clean
```

and you should be all set; if that doesn't work, delete the entire `target` directory.

Comment: optionally to be more sure, do a grails clean-all or delete the target folder manually.